# How to use AMAZON_COGNITO_USER_POOLS with apollo-client

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-web-services, next.js, apollo-client

I am trying to populate my jwtToken with the newer `@aws-amplify` packages and it is proving somewhat difficult.

When trying to run a `Query` I will get the following error: `Uncaught (in promise) No current user`

I can see from the source that if I have auth type set to `AMAZON_COGNITO_USER_POOLS` then I have to use a [jwt token](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-mobile-appsync-sdk-js/blob/139a9775eebe6ac8a9df0b72975b522eeb2867cf/packages/aws-appsync-auth-link/src/auth-link.ts#L156)

```
        case AUTH_TYPE.AMAZON_COGNITO_USER_POOLS:
        case AUTH_TYPE.OPENID_CONNECT:
            const { jwtToken = '' } = auth;
            promise = headerBasedAuth({ header: 'Authorization', value: jwtToken }, operation, forward);
```

So this leads me to trying to generate my JWT token and this is where my knowledge fails me. I know that   `jwtToken: async () => (await Auth.currentSession()).getIdToken().getJwtToken(),` returns a promise as is required as seen in the above code... So I cannot see why this would fail?

## _app.js (next.js)

```
import Amplify from '@aws-amplify/core'
import { Auth } from '@aws-amplify/auth'
import { ApolloProvider } from '@apollo/react-hooks'
import { ApolloLink } from 'apollo-link'
import { createAuthLink } from 'aws-appsync-auth-link'
import { InMemoryCache, ApolloClient } from '@apollo/client'
import { createHttpLink } from 'apollo-link-http'

import awsExports from '../aws-exports'

Amplify.configure(awsExports)
Auth.configure(awsExports)

const url = awsExports.aws_appsync_graphqlEndpoint
const region = awsExports.aws_appsync_region

const auth = {
  type: awsExports.aws_appsync_authenticationType,
  jwtToken: async () => (await Auth.currentSession()).getIdToken().getJwtToken(),
}
const link = ApolloLink.from([createAuthLink({ url, region, auth }), createHttpLink({ uri: url })])
const client = new ApolloClient({
  link,
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
})

const MyApp = function ({ Component, pageProps, router }) {
  return (
        .....
          <ApolloProvider client={client}>
        .....
  )
}

export default MyApp
```

Answer (score 4):

```
jwtToken: async () => (await Auth.currentSession()).getIdToken().getJwtToken()
```

This is a partial correct implementation and would work just fine when the user is already logged in.

`Auth.currentSession()` fails with `Uncaught (in promise) No current user` when the user has not logged in.

The following would show the error in action

```
 Amplify.configure(awsExports);

 Auth.signOut()
    .then(_ => auth.jwtToken())
    .then(console.log)
    .catch(console.error);
```

The following is an example where you would get the token (Replace username and password in the code)

```
Amplify.configure(awsExports);

Auth.signIn(<username>, <password>)
    .then(_ => auth.jwtToken())
    .then(console.log)
    .catch(console.error);
```

The solution for this problem would be to ensure you ask for the token when the user is logged in or ensure handling the error gracefully.

Update:

If there are any public queries, I would say add the api-key based auth in addition to the Cognito auth for the AppSync GraphQL endpoint (`Additional authorization providers` in AppSync settings). In the example below, `id` and `publicProperty` can be accessed via `somePublicQuery` with the configured API Key

```
type Query {
  somePublicQuery:[SomeModel!]!
  @aws_api_key
}

type SomeModel {
  id: ID! @aws_api_key
  privateProperty: String!
  publicProperty: String! @aws_api_key
}
```

If I refer to the example pointed in the question, then this is what would change on the client side.

`headerBasedAuth` can take an Array of headers, one for the api-key, one for the Cognito token.

```
const headerBasedAuth = async ( authHeaders: Array<Headers> = [], operation, forward) => {
  const origContext = operation.getContext();
  let headers = {
    ...origContext.headers,
    [USER_AGENT_HEADER]: USER_AGENT,
  };

  for ( let authHeader of authHeaders) { // Handle the array of auth headers
    let { header, value } = authHeader;
    if (header && value) {
      const headerValue = typeof value === 'function' ? await value.call(undefined) : await value;

      headers = {
          ...{ [header]: headerValue },
          ...headers
      };
    }
  }

  operation.setContext({
      ...origContext,
      headers,
  });

  return forward(operation);

};
```

In the `authLink` function, instead of the switch statement, you would have some thing like this

```
const { apiKey = '', jwtToken = '' } = auth;
promise = headerBasedAuth([{ header: 'X-Api-Key', value: apiKey }, { header: 'Authorization', value: jwtToken }], operation, forward);
```

and finally the `auth` object would look something like this

```
const auth = {
  apiKey: awsExports.aws_appsync_apiKey, //Add apiKey to your aws-exports
  jwtToken: async () => {
      try {
        return (await Auth.currentSession()).getIdToken().getJwtToken()
      } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
        return ""; // In case you don't get the token, hopefully that is a public api and that should work with the API Key alone.
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks GSSWain, I assume then, for queries that are public I make sure my roles are updated in my schema to be `role: public`?

Comment: Thank you very much again @GSSWain! I appreciate the in depth and look forward to check this tomorrow :)
I do have another generalised question about RDS MySQL db and app sync too if you're intetrested :D https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64176243/failed-to-start-api-mock-endpoint-error-cloudformation-stack-parameter-rdsregio

Comment: This was very helpful, much appreciated!